# I’m using Zorin OS 17 and my laptop keeps getting on AirPlane mode after waking up and it won’t disable. Please help fix this forever

Tags: wifi, suspend

**My laptop keeps getting in airplane mode when I wakeup the laptop and I can't disable it to use wifi**. The airplane mode won't turn off on clicking and the wifi is disabled because of this. However, this is solves itself when I reboot the system. But I don't want this to keep happening. (My laptop hardware is fully functional as I've published this question from it. The only problem is the buggy OS)

I've recently transitioned from windows 10 to zorin os 17 due to limited system resources. But I'm sure that the problem I'm facing is because of some software issues. Since I'm new to linux, I don't really know what to do or where to search. The easiest way was here. And I hope I'll find a fix for it.

Thank you!

Comment: In most laptops, there's a key (or key combination) on the keyboard to ensble/disable Airplane mode. Search your keyboard,  read manufacturer's documents.

Comment: Yes there is. But it doesn't work. The only resolve for it is rebooting. I believe there must be some problem from the network settings, just I'm not aware about it or how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, it *can* be an OS issue but most likely is a UEFI "bug". Update it if available *then* troubleshoot from there.